# Jupyter Notebook Error Downloading as PDF

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook, pandoc

I'm getting the error below when I try to download a jupyter notebook as a pdf on my mac.  I installed pandoc and basicTex yesterday, could the issue be that I didn't install latex?  Or is it some other issue?  Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

```
Error:

nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 22 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/palatino.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))

! LaTeX Error: File `adjustbox.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.42     \usepackage
                    {xcolor} % Allow colors to be defined^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by just doing the full macTex install.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me(only for ubuntu/debian).

sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex